# Appium + wd (nodejs) get sibling element

Tags: android, node.js, appium

I have an appium (android blackbox testing) problem on nodejs using wd:

Currently I'm not able to get a sibling element. The Id's are not unique and the schema is always the same ->

```
ListView
  |
  |
  Frame
  | |
  | |
  | TextView[@text headline0]
  | |
  | | 
  | Button //no text - just an icon
  |
  Frame
  | |
  | |
  | TextView[@text headline1]
  | |
  | | 
  | Button //no text - just an icon
  |
  Frame
  | |
  ...
```

My problem is, that I want to click the button next to eg. headline9. I wrote a `scrollToElement(title)` function which scrolls as long as "headline9" is visible..

But now I can't use a xpath like `[//Frame[@index="9"]/]` because it seems that the indices start again from 0 in the currently visible area ... So that maybe `@index="9"` became `@index=2` or sometimes `@index=1`..

Now is my idea to select the button using something like:

```
  .elementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='headline9']/../android.widget.Button")
```

But it seems that it does not work (cannot find the element)

Does anybody else have an idea?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get all your TextViews by `elementsByXPath()` and then all the Buttons the same way. If TextViews Text is equal to your "headline9" return the Button, else iterate through the found TextViews. If you can't find it on the visible area, scroll and do the serach again.

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 (function yourfunctionId(id, context){
  elementsByXPath(Frame[@index=id]TextView){
   elementsByXPath(Frame[@index=id]Button){
    if(TextView[0] === 'undefined'){
     //scroll in ListView
     //call your function recursively from begin (id =0)
     yourfunction(0)
    }
    if(TextView[0].getAttribute('name') == 'headline9'){
     return Button[0]
    }
    else{
     //next
     //call your function recursively
     yourfunction(id++)
    }
   }
  }
)}
```

Either you scroll for the size of von Frame-Element or you maybe have to check is the firsts Frame ist partially visible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
var elemList = yield driver.elementsByClassName('android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat'); //get List of elements 
for(let elem of elemList) {
    //traverse list of elements
    let text = yield elem.elementById('subElementId').text(); //find subElement
    //Your code logic
 }
```

Get list of elements and then find the subElement. I am using "yiewd" library, for "wd" concept is same.
Thanks!